# How to write script in javascript in view page using codeigniter?need support

Tags: php, jquery

I am new in codeigniter,

I want to do ajax call like delete,When I open script tag and make Jquery event like button click and test  its work or not like making alert() nothing happen but if I write this event in main js file.

This is my view page

```
<div class="userdata table-responsive">
    <a href="<?php echo site_url("Users/disactivusers")?>">show disactive users</a>
    <table class="table table-responsive table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>name</th>
            <th> full name</th>
            <th>email</th>
            <th>usertype</th>
            <th>status</th>
            <th>reg date</th>
            <th>reg time</th>
            <th>delete</th>
            <th>edit</th>
            <th>Activate</th>
            <th>disactivate</th>

        </tr>
        <?php
            if(is_array($allUsers) && count($allUsers)>0){
                foreach ($allUsers as $user):
                    echo '<tr>
                            <td>'.$user->id.'</td>
                             <td>'.$user->username.'</td>
                              <td>'.$user->fullname.'</td>
                              <td>'.$user->email.'</td>
                              <td>'.$user->groubid.'</td>';
                                    if($user->regstatus==1){
                                        $shape='<label class="label label-success">activated</label>';
                                    }else{
                                        $shape='<label class="label label-danger">disactive</label>';
                                    }
                            echo ' <td>'.$shape.'</td>
                              <td>'.$user->date.'</td>
                              <td>'.$user->time.'</td>

                                <td><button class="deletenew" id="'.$user->id.'">deletenew</button></td>
                            <td><a class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" href="'.site_url("Users/delete/$user->id") .'">delete</a></td>';

                         echo '   <td><a  class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" href="'.site_url("Users/edit/$user->id") .'">edit</a></td>';


                      echo'      <td><a class="btn btn-info btn-xs"  href="'.site_url("Users/activate/$user->id") .'">Enable</a></td>
      <td><a class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"  href="'.site_url("Users/disactivate/$user->id") .'">Disable</a></td>
                        </tr>';
                endforeach;
            }else{
                echo '<tr>
                        <td colspan="4">no editor found</td>
                    </tr>';
            }
        ?>


    </table>
</div>
```

**this is my jquere code**

```
<script>
    $(".deletenew").on("click",function () {
        alert()
    })

</script>
```

**and after i click this button nothing happen
please help me**

Comment: Combine both those answers below. You need to make sure jquery is loaded before your script, and you need to wrap the event handler in the .ready method.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a jquery running? E.g.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script
            src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button class="deletenew">deletenew</button>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $(".deletenew").on("click", function () {
                    alert('delete!');
                })
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```